# Error on YTBPlayer: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm making an app on Android Studio where the first activity is a YouTube Player taken from the YouTube API, but when I try to add button or other on top of player I get this error.

`YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.Button{af8c494 VFED..C.. ........ 978,0-1080,148 #7f07006a app:id/exit_button}`

The view is inside the YouTubePlayerView, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being:

> left: 978, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 1772..

So I've three question.

1. It's possible resolve this error?
2. If not, it's legal modify the YouTube API?
3. Do you know other library like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is possible to solve that error: you can't have any View overlaying Google's YouTube Player. The only way to use Google's library is to make sure that their constraints are satisfied.
2. Google's YouTube Player API is not open source, there's no way for you to change its behavior.
3. Yes, [Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player). This library automatically solves both problems. You can overlay whatever you want to the player and, if you need to, you can customize the code, being it an open source project. Also the library do not requires the users to have the official YouTube app installed on the phone, and gives you freedom on how you want to customize the UI of the player.

Comment: Ty,  i'll try to use the library is a bit hard but it seems perfect for me!
Ti offro un caffè!

Comment: @Trusted If you have any suggestion to make it simpler to use, open an issue on the github page (y)